# VsCode Extension: Rename Symbols

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any why to trigger Rename Variable from a Extension?

I found an [example](https://github.com/Jason-Rev/vscode-spell-checker/blob/master/client/src/commands.ts#L12) how to rename a certain word in a file, but the reference variables keep the same as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider` command:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider',
    vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri,
    new vscode.Position(targetLine, targetCharacter),
    'newSymbolName').then(edit => {
        if (!edit) {
            return false;
        }
        return vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
    })
```

This will utilize the `RenameProvider` that is registered for the target file. If no such `RenameProvider` exists, you will need to implement one

Comment: I got an error on `return vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);` for **edit**:
_Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WorkspaceEdit'. Property 'size' is missing in type '{}'._

Comment: If you're working in TypeScript, you'll need to specify the return type by using `executeCommand<vscode.WorkspaceEdit>(...)`