# VSCode Extension - Rename Symbols

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have seen this link:
[VsCode Extension: Rename Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839773/vscode-extension-rename-symbols)

but it doesn't solve my questions.

My problem is that I only have a file as context, not some kind of cursor position.  I would like to find the position of a certain symbolname in it (in my case, object name in al language - but that's besides the point).
I know the first match of a certain text will be the symbol ...

Thing is, I need code to be able to rename the symbol, and I have two problems with the code that I found in the link above:
first, as said, I don't know how I can get to the position of a certain string. I can get to the index, but not the position.
second, the last line of that example doesn't compile, since the "edit" variable is of type {}, and isn't allowed as a parameter in the ApplyEdit function.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in rename ui is designed for renaming a symbol as a specific location.

If you want to rename a symbol in a file without using the current position, you can build your own flow using `vscode.showInputBox` to prompt the user for the new name and `WorkspaceEdit` + `applyEdit` to perform the rename itself

Comment: For some reason after I try to rename symbols via shortcut it also formats the whole python file, even though formating is disabled and there is no other shortcut for the keys.